# How to share spring bean / component between JUnit and Cucumber BDD tests

Tags: java, spring, cucumber

I have stumbled upon one issue. I am using Spring for DI in my BDD tests. My components are Glue Scoped by marking components with **@Scope("cucumber-glue")**. But the issue now I am facing is this components are also needed to be used in my JUnit based tests. While trying to Autowire my components spring throws:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '<bean name>': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'cucumber-glue'
```

As per the suggestion in one of the older reported git hub issues I tried registering **GlueCodeScope** to **glueCustomConfigurer** Bean but that class is package restricted so I am unable to access it. Is there another way via which I can continue to use my components in BDD as well as JUnit tests. Note I have to use cucumber-glue scope in order to ensure my tests can run in parallel and that each scenario receives a fresh bean.